# Ruby Slim - Embed JSON in DOM Attribute

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, slim-lang

How to embed a JSON string in a DOM element as a Data attribute using SLIM and Rails. I managed to do this using ERB.

I want to embed a Ruby hash to a DOM element Data attribute.

```rb
product_data = {
  name: "Test Product",
  price: 100_00,
}
```

**I want it some thing like this done with SLIM**:

```html
<div data-product-info='{"name": "Test Product", "price": 10000}'></div>
```

So that I can read it in JS like:

```js
var productInfo = $('#product-modal').data('product-info');
cosole.log(productInfo.name);
```

In ERB I would do some thing like this:

```
<div data-product-info="<%= product_info.to_json %>"></div>
```

I tried various ways to get it done in SLIM but am lost. Using ERB is not an option, unfortunately. This is because I am using it in Trailblazer Cell and for some reason, ERB is not supported.

Even when I use a plain string I get issues like:

```
#product-modal.modal.fade[tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-label="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-test='{"a": 10, "b": 20}']
```

```html
<div aria-label="myModalLabel" class="modal fade show" data-product-info="{" name":="" 10000,="" "price":="" 10000}"="" id="product-modal" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-modal="true" style="display: block;">
```

Comment: Is using JSON some kind of requirement for trailblazer? Seems kind of wonky when you can just use one data attrbute per attribute instead and not have to deal with escaping (which is why your code doesn't work) or parsing it on the client side as `element.dataset` will contain a key for each data attribute anyways.

Comment: You could possibly do something like `#product-modal.modal.fade[..., data-test=escape_javascript(product_info.to_json)]`. This is really so long and hairy though that you should consider writing a helper method.

Comment: @max it's not a requirement in trailblazer. only issue i had was that it was not detecting erb files even when `cells-erb` was included. I wasn't sure if it was a `cells-slim` issue. That is why I mentioned it.

Comment: @max I need to pass about 20 attributes. to the modal. Product info is one of the configuration options to pass to the modal. I tried to do something in the line `"#{j({...}.to_json)}"` with no success. I also think I am going to have to use multiple data attributes.

Comment: @max: I think its a limitation with using `#product-modal[ ... ]` for configuring the element. Instead when using `#product-modal*{ ... }` it works as anticipated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are experiencing a similar situation, you can include JSON data as an attribute (or data attribute).

It seems to be a limitation with the way I was defining the attributes of the element.

```
#product-modal.modal.fade[tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-label="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-product-info=(product_modal_data model.product)]
```

Instead, use `*{}`

```
#product-modal.modal.fade*{tabindex: "-1", role: "dialog", "aria-label" => "myModalLabel", "aria-hidden" => "true", "data-product-info" => {a: 10, b: 20}.to_json}
```

I hope I could get what `*{}` is called, but its Saturday. I will update the answer on Monday.